# Dart Assign List of Object

Tags: dart

I have a class X with attributes

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
```

And I have class Y with attributes

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
```

How do we assign class Y to class X without assigning one by one?
I hope there is less troublesome method like x.add(y) but excluding certain attributes.
 Is this possible?

Comment: You have to assign one-by one. Destructuring might help and is being discussed https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/207

Comment: wow thanks for pointing that one out. that's good enough for me to mark yours as answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to assign one-by one.

Destructuring might help and is being discussed https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/207